# How do i make my nav bar transparent when I scroll down and come back when I scroll up or when I hover my mouse over is?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do i make my nav bar transparent when I scroll down and come back when I scroll up or when I hover my mouse over it? I tride to do this with jquery but i didn't really work.
Here's My HTML and CSS:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="LunchWebsiteCSS.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(window).scroll(
                {
                    previousTop: 0
                }, 
                function () {
                var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                if (currentTop < this.previousTop) {
                    //$(".sidebar em").text("Up"); /* optional for demo */
                    $(".nav").css({ opacity: 0.5 });
                } else {
                    //$(".sidebar em").text("Down");
                    $(".nav").css({ opacity: 0 });
                }
                this.previousTop = currentTop;
            });

        });
    </script>
    <script src="js/jjquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <li><a href="#">Browse</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a>

                </li>
                <li>BHS Lunch</li>
                <li><a href="#">Log In</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Help</a>

                </li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
```

```
.nav {
height: 35px;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
width: 100%;
/*border: 1px solid black;*/
/*background-color: #AA3C39;*/
background-color: #AA3C39;
/*opacity: 0.7;*/
position: fixed;
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can do it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function(){

    if($(window).scrollTop()>100)
    $(".nav").css({"background-color" : "rgba(0,0,0,.5)"});

    else
    $(".nav").css({"background-color" : "rgba(0,0,0,1)"});


    });

});
```

Use CSS to see it back on hover

```
.nav:hover
{
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answering so fast, but do you know how to make it re-appear when the mouse hovers over it? Also do you know how to make it re-appear when you just scroll up a little and not all the way to the top?

Comment: Please open another thread to ask more. See the updated answer. If it solves your problem please consider voting it up and marking it as correct answer.